# Sending email via libCURL

Tags: c++, email, curl, gmail, libcurl

In Linux you can use

```
curl -n --ssl-reqd --mail-from "<$from_address>" --mail-rcpt "<$to_address>" \
     --url smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 -T message.txt -u "$username:$password"
```

to send an email via Gmail.

How can I replicate this using libCURL for C++ using the method `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ' ');`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the libCurl example [smtp-tls.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html), the first link found after doing [Google: libCURL send email](http://www.google.com/search?q=libCURL%20send%20email)